# SSRS 2005, "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified" on Drillthrough

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportingservices-2005

I'm using the ReportViewer control on my ASP.Net web application and there I have a main report that calls many sub-reports with drillthrough.
When I get to a sub-report for the first time, it works fine. But when I go back to the main report, and then try to get to another sub-report, I have:

> "Some parameters or credentials have not been specified".

This problem only happens when I run the application from a client because when I run it on the server, it works fine.

This is my code (omitting the unnecessary lines):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack  )
    {
        string uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToString();
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(uri);

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/RepNet/LaFuenteOperaciones";
        List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Date", Session["Date"].ToString()));
        parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Id", Session["Id"].ToString()));

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        ReportViewer1.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the sub-report to parent report.

It would be such case where parameter are passing to only main reports but due to no linking of sub report with main report,its throwing such error.

Comment: Yes, they all are linked, that's why they can be showed the first time. The problem is when I try to open any of them after I have already opened one.